# Tooltip component not working using Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to use https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tooltips in my rails app. I am not sure where I am going wrong but this is not working. Help me figure out the problem.

When I try to inspect the element this is how it shows

```
<div class="flex add-col-padding-left xs1 md6">
 <span class="tooltip tooltip--bottom">
  <div class="tooltip__content" style="left: 0px; opacity: 0; top: 12px; z-index: 0; display: none;">
   <i dark="" class="material-icons icon-black">
    question_answer
   </i> 
   <span>Tooltip</span>
  </div>
  <span></span>
 </span>
</div>
```

index.js

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  theme: colors
});
```

index.vue

```
<v-tooltip bottom>
 <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
  <i dark v-on="on" class="material-icons icon-black">
   question_answer
  </i>                          
 </template>
 <span>Tooltip</span>
</v-tooltip>
```

Comment: I copied your code into this [codepen](https://codepen.io/sthotakura/pen/BaNBNPz), and it seems to work okay.

Comment: @sthotakura yes, But I don't know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Is this a browser issue? which browser you are using to test?

Comment: @hasan05 chrome

Comment: any console error?

Comment: your code is working, seems your problem is in your vuetify version, please upgrade it. I solved it also by upgrading my vuetify version.